# "У всех было приятное настроение": правильная грамматическая основа

Tags: синтаксис

Как правильно обозначить грамматическую основу в предложении: "У всех было приятное настроение"?
Настроение было? Настроение было приятное?

Answer (score 3):

*"Настроение"* — подлежащее, *"было приятное"* — сказуемое. Сказуемое именно такое потому, что смысл предложения в том, что настроение было приятное, а не в том, что оно просто было.

Comment: Я согласился бы с Вами, если бы предложение было построено так: "Настроение у всех было приятное". Но ведь оно другое. Известны примеры совершенно различного разбора,казалось бы, одинаковых фраз: "Новый дом" и "Дом новый". Не кажется ли Вам, что нечто похожее Вы сделали и с рассматриваемым предложением, поменяв местами слова?

Comment: Нет, мне так не кажется.

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемые форумчане, давайте вернёмся к науке и к вопросу. Мы, по-моему, совсем запутали Ирину.У неё такой путаницы в голове нет. Она спрашивает, что является сказуемым - "было" или "было приятным".Такая сложность среди учеников есть.Валентин ей ответил верно, объяснил тоже.

Мой ответ уже для всех "несогласных".
Если бы это был синтаксический разбор профессиональный - на уровне студента филфака, то он бы выглядел так(не полный, а только по членам предложения): У всех было приятное настроение.-предикативная единица (предложение)состоит из грамматической основы было приятное настроение и детерминанта у всех.(детерминант - неприсловный член предложения, относящийся ко всей грамматической основе, а не к одному её члену).Это классический детерминант - дополнение со значением наличия, стоящий в начале предложения и означающий, что всё, о чём говорится, имеется в наличии У ВСЕХ.Даже слабые студенты его сейчас определяют легко. Так что же было у всех? - у всех было приятное настроение.Как найти подлежащее? Найдём тему и рему. Тема - предмет разговора. О чём говорится?-о настроении.Настроение - подлежащее. Рема - что нового о нём сообщено? - что оно приятное, а не то, что оно имелось в наличии. Следовательно, БЫЛО ПРИЯТНОЕ - составное именное сказуемое, где БЫЛО - отвлечённая глагольная связка прош. врем.(могла бы быть в настоящем - нулевая), приятное - качественное имя прилагательное, которое и несёт основную смысловую нагрузку.

А вот БЫЛО было бы сказуемым в таком предложении:А приятное настроение-то всё-таки было.

Comment: Людмила, просветите почему в предложении "у всех было настроение" говорится о "настроении", а "у всех было тяжело на душе" не о "тяжело на душе"?

Comment: Не передёргивайте."Тяжело на душе" - безличное, сказ.-категория состояния "тяжело". На душе - обстоят. Совершенно разные конструкции. Складывается представление, что Вы их не различаете, посмотрите теорию безличного предложения и  способы выражения сказуемого в нём.

Answer (score 1):

Предмет речи - "приятное настроение". Что о нем говорится? Что оно было, т.е. существовало. Значит, подлежащее - "приятное настроение", сказуемое - "было"

Comment: *"Вчера"* — обстоятельство, а не сказуемое.

Comment: "Приятное настроение" не может быть подлежащим, это не слитное сочетание, не фразеологизм, вполне свободное, приятное - или определение, или сказуемое. Думаю, всё же сказуемое, т.к. что?-настроение, что о нём говорится?- что оно было приятное, а не просто было. Прав Валентин. Вчера-когда?-точно обстоятельство, сказуемым быть не может, Ваше рассуждение касается только наречий на -О.

Comment: >т.к. что?-настроение, что о   
  
Вы тоже считаете "настроение" подлежащим?
У всех было по рублю. "По рублю" - подлежащие?! Или подлежащее с предлогом?!  

Про то, почему только *неразрывные* фразеологизмы могут быть подлежащим, я даже боюсь спрашивать.
//-----

Можете меня снова закидывать помидорами, но мне "было настроение" куда больше напоминает составное именное сказуемое в безличном предложении. 
Может я, конечно, сегодня и не в форме...

Comment: А Вы всерьёз считаете эти конструкции равнозначными?Сколько у них денег?-денег было по рублю -генитивное с пропуском "денег" - приближено к безличному .Было по рублю-сказуемое. Каково было у всех настроение?- настроение у всех было приятное. Про что спрашивается? -про настроение. А вот безличным было бы, если б  спросили: Каково всем? - всем было приятно. Не знаю про форму,может, не в ней дело, а в желании найти что-то оригинальное? Не согласиться с очевидным? Или нас подзавести.

Comment: Насчёт подлежащих - подлежащее может быть выражено какой-либо частью речи с предметным значением в им. падеже, или независимым инфинитивом, выражающим действие-состояние, иногда с управляемым словом, или слитным сочетанием(фразеологизм, сост. геогр. название,количественно-именное сочетание,сочет. типа один из вас, что-то родное, дед с матерью). Если это разложимое сочетание, его разлагают на разные члены предложения.

Comment: >А Вы всерьёз считаете эти конструкции равнозначными?  
  
Пока не увижу причин считать иное. 

Все бы ничего, но как вы подаете - это замкнутый круг. Вы покажите чем они отличаются с точки зрения исходного тезиса (*член предложения, отвечающий на вопрос "было что?" является подлежащим*) тогда будете вопросы задавать "сколько" и "почем".

ЗЫ Нет там пропущенного "денег" - и быть не может. По одному сыну у них было. Или тоже "по  одному ребенку детей"?

Comment: А о чём же вы спрашиваете? Не о детях? сколько у них было детей? - по одному сыну у каждого. Это ситуативно неполное предложение Речь о детях - значит,их и было по одному. Можно спросить: сколько у них было сыновей?Если я спрошу: что у них было(в карманах), то ответ будет: деньги. А я спрашиваю, сколько было денег, это меня интересует, а не про что идёт речь. В карманах было много денег. Что было в карманах?-много денег. Много денег - подлежащее. Это слитное сочетание.

Comment: grumant,"Было ощущение праздника". Субъект(подлежащее) - ощущение.Что оно делало?-было.Какое ощущение?-праздника - определение с оттенком дополнения.Безличным будет "Было празднично". Было ощущение праздника - синонимичная двусоставная синтаксическая конструкция. Смотрим на синтаксис, а не на общее значение.Было темно - безличное. Всё было тёмным - двусоставное. А речь идёт об одном и том же.Было минус сорок - безличное. Температура была минус сорок - двусоставное.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю Людмилу. Где-то я уже писала, что на синтаксис можно смотреть по-разному. Есть структурный синтаксис (традиционный), есть коммуникативный.Вот и спорят здесь люди, исходя из разных посылов. Те, у кого опыта в анализе предложений больше(учителя,преподаватели) явно смотрят на предложение как на структуру, придерживаются позиций традиционного синтаксиса. Другие смешивают эти два подхода.  Поэтому и не договоримся.

Answer (score 1):

Если считать сказуемым *было*, то получается, что в предложении утверждается, что настроение (приятное настроение) просто было, то есть существовало, имелось в наличии. А здесь важно, что оно не просто было, а было приятное. Основную смысловую нагрузгу несёт на себе слово *приятное*. Значит, *было* - это глагол-связка в составном именном сказуемом. Мне это представляется так.))

Answer (score 1):

Мне  в  этом  предложении  главным  кажется  словосочетание  "у  всех",  но,  поскольку  оно  не  может  быть  подлежащим,  предложение  безличное :  сказуемое - было,  настроение  - дополнение,  приятное  -  определение.

Comment: Настроение -  в им. п., след-но, оно подлежащее.

Comment: А  почему  не  винительном ?

Comment: Потому что было - непереходный глагол. Было кого? что? - не по-русски

Comment: Падеж-то именительный, но это еще не значит, что это подлежащее.

Answer (score 0):

"У всех было прекрасное настроение, но потом оно бесследно испарилось." В таком варианте в первой части сложносочиненного предложения сказуемое "было".

Comment: Согласна, но в предложенном примере сказуемое "было приятное"

Comment: Не может грамматика зависеть от контекста.

Comment: Это как? От чего же она зависит?. Вы какой контекст имеете в виду? Языковой контекст - языковые единицы, составляющие окружение данной единицы в пределах предложения. Как же от них не зависит? Она их организовывает и зависит от их состава.Или общий смысл? Ситуацию?
И от этого зависит. Ситуация порождает лексику, лексику организует грамматика. Они взаимосвязаны - единство формы и содержания. Грамматика помогает нам выразить наши мысли и чувства.Пример: казнить нельзя помиловать.Как решишь,так и выделишь повелительную конструкцию

Comment: >Вы какой контекст...
  
Зачем гадать? Я про фразу <<*В таком варианте в первой части сложносочиненного предложения сказуемое "было"*>>.  

>От чего же она зависит?.  
  
Ни от чего. Она объективна. Я думаю, Вы это прекрасно понимаете. Философию дуализма опускаю.

А то, о чем вы пишете, не является *зависимостью*. 
"Казнить нельзя помиловать." Это-то тут причем? Здесь правописание помогает понять грамматику. И через неё - смысл. Но **понять**, **установить**, но никак не изменить. 
У нас-то получается, что одна и та же фраза меняет грамматику от контекста: "в таком варианте".

Comment: Приводя пример сложного предложения, я пыталась деликатно намекнуть, что если "в таком варианте" нет сомнений в сказуемом "было", то и в простом предложении вне контекста этим сомнениям неоткуда появиться)))

Comment: Правильно, я так и понял. И хорошо намекнули кстати.
А Вам возразили, основываясь на идее контекстной засисимости грамматики. 
На что уже возразил я.    
//-----    
Лишний раз убеждаюсь, что ресурс не приспособлен для ведения "живого" диалога. Каждый пост должен быть оформлен как самодостаточная мысль, никакого контекста - не поймут-с.

Answer (score -1):

Перво-наперво. Если вопрос был чисто школьный, о том как учительнице отвечать, то надо отвечать так, как учительница считает. Скорее всего в школе действительно не заморачиваются и принимают за сказуемое то, что лежит на поверхности, т.е. принимают **настроение** за подлежащее со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Сложнее с принципиальными разногласиями по поводу структуры. 
Перечитал я всё тут сказанное.

Во-первых, за сказуемое можно счесть **было приятное настроение**, но при таком подходе выносить "приятное" за пределы сказуемого было бы нелогичным. Так как нарушалась бы иерархическая структура: некий член предложения (определение "приятное") относился бы к части другого *члена* (сказуемого "настроение"), не являясь при этом частью самого такого члена (сказуемого).

Остаётся два варианта. Сказуемое "было" и сказуемое "было приятное настроение".

Похоже, камень преткновения в том, как вообще трактовать грамматику.
если полагать, что язык вещь субъективная - и его можно трактовать как нам заблагорассудиться (лишь бы не противоречиво), то в соображениях [[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f) (примерно означающих, что все подходы могут быть правильны, но на деле всегда правилен тот, который нам больше подходит) есть резон.
Но я-то всегда придерживался той позиции, что язык - вещь объективная (за исключением правил правописания) и от наших взглядов на него никак не зависит. 
Поэтому вопрос о реальном сказуемом вполне уместен. Или придется признать, что у языка две взаимоисключающие грамматики. Но в определении таких базовых вещей как подлежащее, сказуемое, грамматическая основа и проч. существующие описания грамматики никак не расходятся, во всяком случае - не противоречат друг другу.  Следовательно, у задачи должен быть один-единственный объективный ответ.

Чем руководствуются сторонники школьного подхода ("было" - сказуемое, "настроение" подлежащее)? Только тем, что имеет место согласование (координация) в числе и роде. Никаких других неавторитарных доводов более не увидел. насколько это довод справедлис - и насколько он императивен? Боюсь, что координация здесь далеко не абсолютная. Примеры с "У них было по рублю" я приводил. Чтобы "отмести" этот контрпример потребовалось сразу же изменить грамматику предложения. Я с таким подходом не согласен. Почему вдруг должна меняться грамматика, если я всего лишь одну "ячейку" структуры заполняю другим словом той же грамматической функции - и подлежащее без видимых причин становится дополнением?

С другой стороны, помимо упомянутого требования единства структуры безотносительно к наполнению, есть соображение, что в номинативных языках субъект (производитель действия) и подлежащее - суть одно и то же. "Настроение" никак не может быть производителем действия, это пациенс. Агенс - "все". 
И я все более склоняюсь к этой трактовке. Все вместе (было хорошее настроение) - сказуемое

Да, забыл сказать, почему настроение - не дополнение. 
Попробую для простоты на другом примере. 
У Васи были родители (вчера, в гостях) - У Васи [находятся] родители.
У Васи были родители (вообще, он не сирота) - У Васи есть родители.
В первом случае родители - подлежащее, "были" - смысловой глагол.
Во втором - глагол связка. Под какой случай подходит "У всех было хорошее настроение"? Я сно, что под второй. Т.е. Если "настроение"  - дополнение, то "есть" - глагол связка. Но при нём дополнение в виде именительного падежа (т.е. объектный именительного) возможно только в конструкциях типа "Я - человек" (хотя и тут логичнее "[есть] человек" считать сказуемым). У нас ничего похожего нет. так что доаолнение я на самом деле исключаю.

*ЗЫ Я очень надеюсь, что количество минусов не превысит количество критических содержательных комментариев.*

Comment: Браво! Вместо того чтобы сделать ясным, ещё больше запутали. Зачем Вам контент-анализ   Филлмора? Он нужен для определения глубинных семантических ролей членов предложения в безличных предложениях с возвратным глаголом.У нас глагол не возвратный, обычный - "было".Настроение не может быть подлежащим? Вот загнули! А если так: Настроение моё падало - тоже безличное? Что?-настроение.Подлежащее. Что оно делало?-падало. Настроение было великолепно -Что?-настроение.Подл.Оно каково?-великолепно - сост. именное сказуемое.Вокруг великолепно.-Великолепно - сказуемое безличного предложения.

Comment: Что-то Вы про школьный анализ неуважительно. Он прост и ясен, им только пользоваться надо уметь.В школе действительно  "не заморачиваются" - а зачем? Что?-настроение. Оно было  каково? - было приятным. - составное именное сказуемое ДВУСОСТАВНОГО (а не безличного) предложения. Всем уже понятно, только Вы никак не смиритесь с очевидным.

Comment: А Вы еще не поняли, что спорить бесполезно? Этот человек сам себе и Даль, и Розенталь. И про школу все знает, и про лингвистику. И переубедить его невозможно.

Comment: Лорана! Миллион раз БРАВО!!!

Comment: Я возмущён! ОН вас совсем (затрол..) запутал! Вместо того чтобы ставить ЕМУ минусы, вы теперь, пугливо озираясь, **ставите плюсы себе**! А за *такие* плюсы ведь придётся отчитываться точно так же, как и за минусы.

Comment: Уважаемые, Вы бы не увлекались троллингом. 

По сути. 
>Зачем Вам контент-анализ Филлмора?  
Кто такой Паниковский? Это папа Ваш Паник... Филлмор? Это мой анализ. Я на авторитетов не ссылался. Если у авторитетов есть опровержение моего анализа - прошу. А то, что Пушкин не писал на японском - это не повод говорить, что Басё не поэт.

>Настроение не может быть подлежащим?...
  
Уточните вопрос. В каком случае?

>Настроение моё падало - тоже безличное?  
  
Двусоставное. Вы этого не знали?

Остальное 

>ставите плюсы себе!

Comment: Не Паниковский, а Студебеккер тогда уж.

Comment: Да. Но Студебеккера не помнят. А Паниковский понятен.

Comment: behemothus! Я ничего не говорила о том, что "все подходы могут быть правильны, но на деле всегда правилен тот, который нам больше подходит". Пожалуйста, никогда не разъясняйте мои слова. Вы очень часто слышите не совсем то, о чем вам говорят. Впрочем, это, возможно, издержки виртуального общения.

Comment: @Ларf, я вполне ясно выразился. Я не приписывал Вам свои мысли по поводу Ваших слов. Осмысливать Ваши слова я имею право, надеюсь?
 
Давайте по сути, что, собственно, неправильного я сказал? И как еще Вас понимать? Вот эту особенно часть:
"Те, у кого опыта в анализе предложений больше(учителя,преподаватели) явно смотрят на предложение как на структуру". А остальные, типа, не смотрят?

Comment: А я где-то говорила, что это про Вас? Извините, вынуждена признать правоту Лораны. Спорить бесполезно.

Comment: behemothus, Вы применили термины агенс и пациенс, а это из контент-анализа Филлмора, или это тоже Ваше? Тогда скажите, что это в переводе на Ваш язык, если у Вас агенс - "все"? Этим термином пользуются, чтобы прояснить субъект и объект действия в безличном предложении.У нас не безличное предложение.Вы сказали:" "Настроение" никак не может быть производителем действия, это пациенс".А я Вам привела пример "Настроение моё падало". Настроение - производитель действия, подлежащее.Как и в исходном. Настроение - подлежащее. Было приятное - сказуемое.

Comment: Не может быть такого сказуемого-"настроение было приятное", тогда следует признать, что это безличное предложение,а в нём сказуемое - целое сочетание, которое придётся считать слитным. Это не слитное сочетание. Сказуемое безличного предложения - безличный глагол,(или личный в безличном знач.), безлично-предикативное слово, краткое страдат. причастие в среднем роде, отрицат слово или конструкция, независимый инфинитив. Тоже не подходит.По значению эти глаголы не допускают при себе существительного или местоимения в именит. падеже. Не проходит Ваш вариант

Comment: >агенс и пациенс,
Это из общей лингвистики. Используется, например, при систематизации языков на номинативные и эргативные взамен терминов "объект" и "субъект". Филлмор, даже если это его термины (не знал), там упоминается разве что вскользь. В конструкции  **"У (объекта) есть (субъект)"** я, простите, спинным мозгом чувствую некий эргатив, который только с помощью упомянутых терминов и находит разрешение. Потому и заговорил.

>Не может быть такого сказуемого
Простите, но я спрашивал, почему это не подлежащее. Что мешает объявить его таковым по Вашей логике о теме и реме?